# getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'o'? while parsing java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I wanted to convert from string to java.util.Date. for the same purpose I used following code,

```
String timeStamp = "Mon Feb 14 18:15:39 IST 2011";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date ts = (Date)formatter.parse(timeStamp);
```

The format given to SimpleDateFormat() is format of java.util.Date. When you convert util's Date to string it comes in this format('dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy').
But when I execute code, It gives me Exception. I Don't know what exactly I needed to do to get rid of this problem. I am posting the part of StackTrace of exception. If anybody knows the solution,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Illegal pattern character 'o'     at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:769)
>     at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:576)
>     at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.(SimpleDateFormat.java:501)
>     at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.(SimpleDateFormat.java:476)
>   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

`E` is used for "Day in Week" as text, `M` is the month name.

Comment: Yes, this format is correct. Actually from java docs I got that format for util's Date.toString() function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, it should be `HH` (hours in 0..23) and not `hh` (hours in 1..12. The documentation of Date.toString is quite confusing, I'm just filing a bug report about this.

Answer (score 2):

You've formatted it wrong I believe, if you look here http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html its E for day of the week and M for month

Comment: Your answer is also correc, but same as Andreas's answer. Anyways thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I wrote it as he was writing it. He did answer first though so I really don't mind, as long as you got your question answered!