# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Date java

Tags: java

Getting error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.util.Date.parse(Unknown Source) at java.util.Date.(Unknown Source)

Here is my java code

```
import java.util.Date; 

public class DateCheck { 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String dDate="Sat Apr 11 12:16:44 IST 2015"; 
    Date cDate=null; 
    cDate = new Date(dDate); 
} 
}
```

I am using java 1.6

Comment: try using simpleDateFormtt.parse  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: That's deprecated constructor, you should not use it.

Comment: I got the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993132/getting-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-illegal-pattern-character-o-while

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the method `parse()` of an implementation class of `DateFormat`.
The simplest way is using `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
String dDate="Sat Apr 11 12:16:44 IST 2015"; 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date cDate = df.parse(dDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String dDate="Sat Apr 11 12:16:44 IST 2015"
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMM-yyyy,HH:mm:ss aaa");
Date date = formatter.parse(dDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: The format in your `SimpleDateFormat` does not seem to match the format of the string you are parsing.

Comment: @khelwood, yeah, your right! Sorry for that, just in hurry!